# TypeError: message.guild.channels.cache is not a function

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I would like to know why *message.guild.channels.cache* is not a function
Of course there is a sequel but I show that the main one. If you want the rest, just ask me! ;-;
I seriously need your help, you reading my post!

```
client.on("ready",()=>{
    console.log("TicketBot is online!");
    client.user.setActivity("type !ticket help to get started");
});

client.on("message",async message=>{
    if(message.author.bot||message.type=="dm")return;
    var arg = message.content.toLowerCase().split(" ");
    if(arg[0]!='!ticket')return;
    if(!message.guild.me.hasPermission("MANAGE_CHANNELS")||!message.guild.me.hasPermission("MANAGE_ROLES")){
        message.channel.send("Not enough permissions I require the `MANAGE_CHANNELS` and `MANAGE_ROLES` permission!");
        return;
    }
    let TicketCategory = message.guild.channels.cache.find(channel=>channel.name==="Open Tickets");
    if(TicketCategory==null){
        await message.guild.channels.create('Open Tickets', {
            type: 'category',
            permissionOverwrites: [{
              id: message.guild.id,
              deny: ['READ_MESSAGES']
            }]
          })
          .then(t=>TicketCategory=t)
          .catch(console.error);
    }
```

Comment: On what line is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
client.on("message", async (message) => {
    if (message.author.bot || message.channel.type == "dm") return false;

    const args = message.content.toLowerCase().split(" ");

    if (args[0] == "!ticket") {
        if (!message.guild.me.hasPermission("MANAGE_CHANNELS") || !message.guild.me.hasPermission("MANAGE_ROLES")) return message.channel.send("Not enough permissions I require the `MANAGE_CHANNELS` and `MANAGE_ROLES` permission!");

        const TicketCategory = message.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name == "Open Tickets");

        if (!TicketCategory) {
            message.guild.channels.create("Open Tickets", {
                type: "category",
                // READ_MESSAGES is not a valid permission flag in Discord JS v12.
                // Use READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY or VIEW_CHANNEL.
                permissionOverwrites: [{id: message.guild.roles.everyone, deny: ["READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY"]}]
            }).catch(e => console.log(e));
        }
    }
});
```